# Communication between two graphic cards

Tags: cuda

How does CUDA synchronise two graphic cards? How do they communicate? I have two tesla cards but I don't know how to perform communication between them.

I need to store 5 gb matrix in RAM. Ihave two tesla cards 3gb RAM each. Can I force sync by dividing kernel into smaller ones?

Comment: Can you describe what your goal is?  What computation do you want to perform?

Comment: There is [a good presentation from one of nVidia's webinars](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/cuda_webinars_GPUDirect_uva.pdf) about using multiple GPUs. I recommend reading it, since for now your question is, in my opinion, slightly too vague and broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [tutorial on multi-GPU programming](http://www.gputechconf.com/gtcnew/on-demand-gtc.php?sessionTopic=&searchByKeyword=micikevicius&submit=&select=%20&sessionEvent=&sessionYear=&sessionFormat=#1451) by NVIDIA Developer Technology Engineer Paulius Micikevicius provides a thorough overview of programming in CUDA on multiple GPUs, including communication and synchronization between GPUs.

In summary, the CUDA Runtime API (v4.x and later) provides `cudaMemcpy*` functions providing peer-to-peer copy functionality, and synchronization can be achieved by using the Stream and Event API (e.g. `cudaStreamWaitEvent()`).